# Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http Extension Validator

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, file-upload

I have the next code:

```
$currFile = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$currFile->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg');
```

It works pretty. But if I put `array('jpg','png')` instead of `'jpg'`, only files with jpg extendion works.

How can I set more than 1 extension. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strange. Looks like valid syntax: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html can you try `"jpg,png"`?

Comment: It doesn't. I use Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http, not a Zend_File_Transfer.

Comment: Are you using `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` for any particular reason? Have you tried just using `Zend_File_Transfer`? After all, at the moment, `Zend_File_Transfer` is just a wrapper for `Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http` because there are no other protocols implemented, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of Pekka's suggestion:

```
$currFile->addValidator('Extension', false, 'png,jpg')
```

As Pekka said, if you have not tried it, try the , separated list. But given that only `jpg` files work, even if you add the array or comma separated list I would make sure you are modifying the correct file. To test this, remove the `jpg` all together and just use `png` and see if that validates alone. If not then chances are you are modifying the wrong file. As for you "not using `Zend_File_Transfer`" the adapter you are using is an extension of it, so it has access to the same items / features so the Documentation Pekka linked to is relevant.

Comment: have you find the problem? because I use this syntax and it works well: $upload->addValidator('Extension', true, array('csv', 'txt', 'xls'));
and I'm pretty sure the second parameter was not the problem. So, were you getting the correct file @plutov ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify if the extensions are allowed or denied

```
$currFile->addValidator('Extension', false, array('extension1' => 'png,jpg', 'case' => true))
```

You can take a look in the Zend documentation

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/migration.17.html